# Does anybody know a good introduction to homology?

Tags: soft-question, homology-cohomology, online-resources

Essentially what the title says. I need something that will give me a decent introduction into homology theory. I don't need too deep of an understanding, just enough to get through a paper I'm reading.

As has been suggested, the paper I'm reading is On Khovanov's Categorification of the Jones Polynomial, by Dror Bar-Natan, available here:
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0201043

Also I should probably add, I'm a rising sophomore (undergraduate) so I really don't have the background that I should to be reading about homology theory. But my research advisor gave it to me, so I've got to get through this.

Comment: How about telling us what paper you're reading, so that those who know about homology can estimate how much you need to know? As a generic first step, the first few chapters of Vick's book *Homology Theory* are fairly nice, at least if you want the topological as well as the algebraic content of the theory.

Comment: Good idea, thanks

Comment: I think pretty much any introductory book should do. As far as I can tell, the paper does not actually use any advanced concepts, just the idea of chain complexes and their homology (which are just suitable quotients depending on the maps).

Comment: Yeah you're spot on. That's why I said I don't need anything too thorough. I just have no idea what books are good for the subject

Comment: I think you might actually get  by just by looking up the definitions on Wikipedia

Comment: Why don't you just ask your advisor? He should know both your current knowledge level and what is required to understand that article, so he should be able to give you a spot-on suggestion (or to just explain it to you himself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, the  book "Graphs, Surfaces and Homology" (3rd ed.) by Peter Giblin is an outstandingly readable and informative undergraduate introduction to homology.  You probably should for now avoid MacLane's "Homology."  There is no royal road, remember, and you are entering the gates to someplace where no road is a superhighway.